# Severe input latency & lag on Threadripper 2990WX

Tags: windows, performance, lag

**Issue Description**

I have just recently upgraded my CPU to the AMD 2990WX and I started noticing VERY high input lag when running about 10 heavier applications or so concurrently (VS, Docker, Hyper-V, Chrome, Teamviewer)

This gets REALLY bad when I have Process Explorer and Resource Monitor open to try and view things. I am talking about 3-5 seconds to switch between windows, 5+ (even up to 10-15) seconds to open up windows explorer. Resource Monitor can't even do anything, it's like its almost entirely frozen. Inputs take forever, I move mouse, a couple of seconds later it all gets queued up and slides along (after I stopped moving). Sound is stuttering, both people speaking to me (Discord) and me talking to them.

What could the cause of this be, how can I even begin to diagnose it? 
Previous to this, I had an Intel 5960x and I was not experiencing these issues. The only change is a new motherboard and CPU.

**Specs/Info:**

- CPU: AMD Threadripper 2990WX (with the enermax cooler)
- Motherboard: ASRock Fatal1ty X399
- Video: nVidia GTX 1080
- SSD: Sa950 PRO NVM.E
- RAM: 8x8GB G.SKILL 2400 MHz
- OS: Windows 10 Exterprise 1803 (freshly reinstalled)
- DxDiag: https://gist.github.com/sdb-dev/16e3a14941640b99c04a059425ce50ae

**Additional Info**

The lag really starts to show when running Teamviewer and Hyper-V (one or two VMs with barely any resource usage) and a couple of idle visual studios (3-5) and chrome. All UI applications experience severe framerate drops (60->20fps every 1-3 seconds), and completely freeze when I try to open an explorer, another application, task manager, etc. The overall system CPU/memory usage are all easily below 20% with this happening.

I have also reinstalled windows just to make sure it was not windows related. Reinstalled only my development tools, discord and teamviewer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be directly related to Hyper-V. Even though I stopped the VMs, it did not help. Once I completely removed Hyper-V, I had no issues at all - I was able to run all of the applications that caused the lag (and many more) with 0 lag.

Answer (score 0):

I think *`speculation`* that this is indeed some form of incompatibility between your AMD hardware and hyper-v.

Firstly I'd suggest checking your virtualization settings in the UEFI. (I'm sure you already did but hey..) And also, I did some light googling and found two interesting things. [This](https://softfamous.com/amd-virtualization-technology-and-microsoft-hyper-v-system-compatibility-check-utility/)&[that](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/check-intel-amd-processor-supports-hyper-v)

Comment: True, it's still a speculation. I will have to re-install it and run the exact same set of software without it and with it.


edit: Also, before I reinstalled Windows I did have VMWare which seemed to lag whenever I booted up as well, but I didn't think anything about it and just uninstalled it. I'll give that a test as well